# Opening .bin file with Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Word 8.0 document stored as .bin file that I'm trying to re-open in MS Word using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop. I can get the document to open and display the contents, however it does not apply any of the styles of the document (such as font size's, underlining etc.)

My code is as follows:

```
object pathToBin = @"\\server\folder\123.bin";
object missingType = Type.Missing;
object readOnly = true;
object isVisible = false;
object documentFormat = WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatDocument97;

Application applicationclass = new Application();
applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref pathToBin,
                                ref readOnly,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref isVisible,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                ref missingType, ref missingType);
applicationclass.Visible = true;
Document document = applicationclass.ActiveDocument;
```

When the document itself is opened up it seems to be literally displaying the styles like this:

```
Heading 1
Heading 1
Heading 2
Heading 2
Heading 3
Heading 3
Hyperlink
Hyperlink
```

etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you any idea what this .bin format actually is? It isn't one of the standard types. What if you open it manually in Word? Is it a .bin  file within a .docx (.zip) file?

Comment: @bibadiak When I open the .bin file in Word manually it's contents are "FileName.doc" then says "Word.Document.8 Embedded" than displays the contents of the .doc file both then says stuff like Heading1 Heading2 Normal Normal Footer etc.  -- Hope that helps clear up some stuff

Comment: I don't know what format that is, sorry. If you can post one of your .bin files somewhere we could look at it, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I see you setting the documentFormat object but don't see you using it as a parameter to your call to Documents.Open.

Given the file extension is .bin, could it be that Word is struggling to figure out the document format with this parameter missing?

Comment: Good point, When I try 'wdOpenFormatDocument97' it gives me the error when trying to call .Open: Word was unable to read this document.  It may be corrupt.

Try one or more of the following:

* Open and Repair the file.

Comment: Not sure that's an improvement :-) Nonetheless You should update your question's code so others don't find the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed @Chris Spicer, since you set `documentFormat`, you should set it when you call `applicationclass.Documents.Open`...

...But also **make sure you set the correct arguments on right places**, since they are actually shifted (you pass `IsVisible` for `Encoding` parameter!).

[Documents.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx) Method

```
Document Open(
[In] ref object FileName,                              PathToBin OK
[In, Optional] ref object ConfirmConversions,          here you have readOnly!
[In, Optional] ref object ReadOnly,                    Missing
[In, Optional] ref object AddToRecentFiles,            Missing
[In, Optional] ref object PasswordDocument,            Missing
[In, Optional] ref object PasswordTemplate,            Missing
[In, Optional] ref object Revert,                      Missing
[In, Optional] ref object WritePasswordDocument,       Missing
[In, Optional] ref object WritePasswordTemplate,       Missing
[In, Optional] ref object Format,                      Missing
[In, Optional] ref object Encoding,                    here you have IsVisible!
[In, Optional] ref object Visible,                     Missing
[In, Optional] ref object OpenAndRepair,               Missing
[In, Optional] ref object DocumentDirection,           Missing
[In, Optional] ref object NoEncodingDialog,            Missing
[In, Optional] ref object XMLTransform                 Missing
```

So this code:

```
applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref pathToBin,
                            ref readOnly,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType, ref isVisible,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType);
```

Should be:

```
applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref pathToBin,
                            ref missingType,
                            ref readOnly, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                            ref missingType, ref documentFormat, ref missingType,
                            ref isVisible, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                            ref missingType, ref missingType);
```

Comment: Great point, thanks for the correction.  Unfortunately, still having the same issues

Comment: @mint Have you tried others fileFormat? Try to use   `wdOpenFormatAllWord` instead. From MSDN: wdOpenFormatAllWord A Microsoft Word format that is backward compatible with earlier versions of Microsoft Word.